# Array in database, use as variable

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am making a prototype invoice thing for practice. I'm using CakePHP 3 and the items are always going to be different so associating them with rows in another table won't work. In each row I have a column named items and in that is an array such as:

```
    array(
      array("Name" => "apples",
        "Desc" => "a fruit called apple",
        "Price" => "1"
      ),
      array("Name" => "orange",
        "Desc" => "oranges",
        "Price" => "2",
      ),
      array("Name" => "watermelon",
        "Desc" => "watermelon",
        "Price" => "6"
      )
);
```

I'm wanting to use that array to build a foreach loop to display all the items in the invoice.

```
    foreach ($items as $i => $row) {

    echo $row['Name'] . $row['Price'] . $row['Desc'] . "<br>";
}
```

I'm trying to use this method to get the data in from the column

```
<?php $items = $billing->items; ?>
```

However this is what I receive:

```
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template\Billing\invoice.ctp, line 56]
```

If I try to echo the data, it echo's it just fine. I don't understand why I can't make it a variable.

```
<?= h($billing->items); ?>
```

Comment: can u print $billing->items as echo '<pre>'; print_r($billing->items )? i thought h function is used for printing db special characters so it is able to convert it in array but normally foreach loop can't do so.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but it does print just like echo using `print_r($billing->items)`

Comment: "_...the items are always going to be different_..." These items look pretty identical to me.

Comment: I had fruit in my mind at the time, but a different user is going to be assigning the Name, Desc, and Price.  So instead of creating new rows each time someone inputs something different and associate them, I decided storing it in an array would be best. If there is something else I can do to simplify it, I'm all for it. I just don't know what there is. @ndm

Comment: Storing items in separate rows and linking them to rows in other tables is exactly what relational databases like MySQL are there for. So how's that in any way a problem? As for your question as it stands, you cannot store an array in the database, you must have converted it into a flat format, and judging from the error you haven't converted it back (properly). Without proper details about that, you probably won't receive any good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Cake only create entities for model associations not columns. In this case if you would have to set properties manually using `Collection` methods of some sort or php `array_*` functions.

Edit:

If you 're storing as a serialised array then you have to deserialise it first

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Not because it's bad, I just really don't understand. I'm looking at the collections method in the manual right now.

Comment: Have you tried creating a separate table for items for example `Cart` hasMany `Item`